# Integrity constraint violated

Tags: sql

The situation is simple, however I can't get why is that error occurs `integrity constraint (SQL_GWMDLLKDECSEPYVDIKOHHICMM.SYS_C007123893) violated`. I'm able to pull the information with `SELECT *` and it returns information.

```
CREATE TABLE Courses(
CourseID int primary key,
DisciplineName varchar(4),
CourseNumber varchar(4),
NumberOfCredits smallint,
YearFirstOffered varchar(4),
CourseTitle varchar(75) 
);

-- Create faculty-courses table

CREATE TABLE FacultyCourses (

FacultyCoursesID int primary key,

CourseID int REFERENCES Courses(CourseID),

FacultyID varchar(30) REFERENCES Faculty(FacultyID));
```

10 entries like that  entry

```
insert into Courses
values (2, 'CMIS','242',3, '2011','Intermediate Programming');
```

and 25 entries like that:

```
--2 record

insert into FacultyCourses

values (2,2,'jsmith');
```

ALL I'm trying to do is to

```
DELETE FROM Courses
WHERE YearFirstOffered='2011';
```

Comment: If you have access to the database gui, expand your constraints folder on the three tables and find the constraint with that id.  Check out its properties to see what fields are giving you the error.  At first glance I'm going to guess it is a constraint on CourseId in the FacultyCourses table and you do not have cascading DELETE enabled.  When you have foreign keys like this you would need to remove the FacultyCourse that references the Course, before removing the Course itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those `REFERENCES` bits in `FacultyCourses` are foreign key specifications, which ensure that each row's `CourseID` (if present) has the same value as a row in `Courses`. When you're trying to delete from `Courses`, by default, the server won't delete rows referenced from `FacultyCourses`.

You can tell the server what to do in this situation by adding an `ON DELETE` clause to the foreign key reference. The default is `ON DELETE NO ACTION`, IIRC, which causes the error you're seeing. You can also say `ON DELETE CASCADE`, which deletes any rows that reference the one being deleted; `ON DELETE SET NULL`, which detaches the referencing rows by setting their `CourseID` to null; or `ON DELETE SET DEFAULT` to set the referencing rows' `CourseID` to the default value. (Since there currently isn't a default value other than null, you probably don't want to do that last one  here.)

If you wanted `ON DELETE CASCADE`, for example, you would change your SQL like so...

```
CREATE TABLE FacultyCourses (
    FacultyCoursesID int primary key,
    CourseID int REFERENCES Courses(CourseID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FacultyID varchar(30) REFERENCES Faculty(FacultyID)
);
```

If you can't change the keys and such, then you need to ensure the SQL doesn't delete referred-to rows.